# Why doesn't hair grow all over your face?

Tags: human-biology

Why doesn't hair grow all over your face?

Surely hair on a face would have blocked the sun and kept it warm.

Or perhaps through natural selection we opted for hairless faces over hairy ones?

Comment: Why doesn't hair grow on the face- because there are no hair follicles in that region of the skin. Actually, in males the hair does grow all over the face except the eye region and forehead. Hair in those regions would block the vision.

Comment: Actually, we do have hair over most of our faces - it's just mostly [vellus hair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vellus_hair) and not as visible.